# Why does my JUnit test (that modifies a database entry) fail

Tags: java, frameworks, junit, playframework-2.0

EDIT: replaced 'retrieve.name == "name1"' by 'retrieve.name.equals("name1")'.

EDIT2: Added @BeforeClass and @AfterClass (credit: http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/06/01/play-framework-2-tutorial-ebean-orm/).

I'm writing JUnit tests for a play web app and for some odd reason I can't seem to modify the database entries. Here's the simplest example I could come up with that illustrates the problem:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws IOException {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase());
    Helpers.start(app);

    server = Ebean.getServer("default");

    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
    config.setDebugSql(true);

    ddl = new DdlGenerator((SpiEbeanServer) server, new H2Platform(), config);

    // drop
    String dropScript = ddl.generateDropDdl();
    ddl.runScript(false, dropScript);

    // create
    String createScript = ddl.generateCreateDdl();
    ddl.runScript(false, createScript);
}

@AfterClass
public static void stopApp() {
    // drop
    String dropScript = ddl.generateDropDdl();
    ddl.runScript(false, dropScript);

    Helpers.stop(app);
}

@Test
public void UserModify(){
    // create user (User extends Model)
    User user = new User();
    user.id = (long) 1;
    user.name = "name1";
    user.save();

    // modify
    user.name = "name2";
    user.update();
    user.save();

    // look-up
    User retrieve = User.find.byId((long) 1);
    assertFalse("Old name", retrieve.name.equals("name1"));
}
```

Needless to say this should pass, but it doesn't... I know you can use "update()" to change database fields, because someone else on the project says he uses it like that and it works.

Play Framework documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Home

Any ideas why this test fails?

Comment: shouldn't retrieve.name equal "name2" after you've modified it? Also, to compare Strings, always use `equals()`

Comment: Changed to 'equals'. I used assertFalse, not assertTrue.

Comment: David, first we need to understand what is the problem you are trying to resolve - test fails for no reason or SQL update is not performed? Or SELECT is not working right?
You probably see generated and executed SQL statements in console?

Comment: Update() doesn't work, but only in the test. Another person of my project uses update() successfully. The look-up works correctly; it's just as if the second user.save() isn't there.

Comment: David, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of a problem in Play Framework.
Play doesn't enhance code in "test" folder, only in "app" folder.
Because of that getters and setters are not generated, and Ebean is relying on setters to detect that object is dirty and to support lazy loading. This way in your case Ebean doesn't know that property was updated on object.

As a simple solution, you can create getters and setters yourself. Also, that seems to be fixed already and probably should be included in next Play release:  https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/test/integrationtest-java/test/models/EbeanEnhancementTest.java

Here's a simple Play project with User model and working test: https://github.com/pharod/so-play2-issue1

See more details on getters and setters generation by Play here, in "Caveats" section near bottom of page: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaEbean

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you should use .equals() for string equality.

But the main problem is that to run this kind of tests (accessing the database) You need a running application.
In play, this could be done, by running a fake application with the test. Check out this guide:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaTest